# How to fix (IndexError: list index out of range) python 2 and 3?

Tags: python

I have This code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import re

url = requests.get('https://rotana.net/%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AC/')
date = re.findall(r'csv\":\"https:\\\/\\\/rotana.net\\\/triAssets\\\/uploads\\\/(\d{4}\W{2}\d{2})\W{2}', url.text)[0].replace('\/', '/')
channel_code = re.findall(r'/\d+\\/\d+\\/(.*?).csv\"', url.text)
channel_code = [ch for ch in channel_code if not '.png' in ch]
for code in channel_code:
    rotana(date, code)
```

And I have got this error on python 3

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm trying to get EPG data last for E2 python device ...

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: You assume that `re.findall` finds something. That may not be the case.

Comment: You should add error detection to the code. What if `requests.get` fails? Check its status code before continuing. What if `findall` doesn't find anything? Again, check. These are cases where you'll have to decide what your error recovery should be. In the end, IndexError isn't a bug - that may be a legitimate way to detect errors in this code. You have to decide what you want to do with that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try except with IndexError to fix the problem

```
try:
    date = re.findall(regex_pattern)[0].replace('\/', '/')
except IndexError:
    print("Date not found!")
    exit()
```